# Trouble with for /f Command in CMD: Handling Spaces in File Path for 'C:\Program Files'

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm encountering an issue while trying to execute a command in Windows Command Prompt (cmd). My goal is to extract the version number of CMake installed on my system. The command I am using is:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %v in ('"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --version ^| findstr /b /c:"cmake version"') do (echo %v)
```

However, when I run this command, I receive the following error message:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The command prompt seems to not properly handle the space in the "Program Files" directory. I've tried enclosing the path in double quotes, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

I would appreciate any insights or solutions to execute this command correctly. Specifically, I'd like to understand how to properly handle spaces in file paths within a `for /f` command in cmd.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**P.S.** I have also posted the question [here](https://t.me/Batch/15147) on Telegram.

Comment: @Compo same error!

Comment: Apologies, @FoadS.Farimani my brain wasn't fully engaged on the task at hand. This will likely do it for you: ```For /F "Tokens=3" %G In ('""%ProgramFiles%\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --version 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIBC:"cmake version""') Do @Echo %G```.

Comment: @Compo this works now! Could you be kind enough to elaborate in an answer on what you did and what mistakes I made?

Comment: The command between the singlequotes within the parentheses is processsed in another cmd instance. The parser sees the outer quotes and drops them leaving everything within untouched.